# App crashes with unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

This is the error Xcode shoy my:

> 2013-10-25 11:43:35.059 ChineseCheckers[7220:c07] -[HomeViewController
>   play:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8a2de20 2013-10-25
>   11:43:35.062 ChineseCheckers[7220:c07] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[HomeViewController play:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x8a2de20'

*** First throw call stack:

> (0x1af7012 0x14a4e7e 0x1b824bd 0x1ae6bbc 0x1ae694e 0xeed2c0 0x1ab6376
>   0x1ab5e06 0x1a9da82 0x1a9cf44 0x1a9ce1b 0x278b7e3 0x278b668 0x3e8ffc
>   0x28fd 0x2def725 0x1) libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an
>   exception (lldb) 0x8a2de20

**I`m traying to put a background sound to my app , I put the sourece code**

```
-(IBAction)play
{
    NSString *soundFilePath =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"larga"ofType: @"mp3"];
    NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: soundFilePath];
    AVAudioPlayer *newPlayer =[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: fileURL error: Nil];

    self.player = newPlayer;

    [self.player prepareToPlay];
    [self.player setDelegate: self];
    [self.player play];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 30 target: self
                                   selector: @selector(play:) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
}

    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    .............................
    ...............................

        [self.player play];
}
```

Comment: What have you done :(

Comment: Edit your code so it looks good.

Comment: No need to use NSTimer to play sound in loop. There is a property self.player.numberOfLoops=-1;

Comment: Right here `[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 30 target: self
                                   selector: @selector(play:) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];` you are calling the selector `play:` on self when clearly your selector is just `play`

Answer (score 9):

With this:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 30 target: self
                               selector: @selector(play:) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
```

You are calling the method play on your view controller, at that method doesn't exist.

Try creating it (remove the : from play: in the selector):

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 30 target: self
                               selector: @selector(play) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];

-(void)play
{
  [self.player play];
}
```

Comment: What is the need of timer ?

Comment: I dont want to ask, I just fixed the crash

Comment: Removing NSTimer will also fix the crash :P